# Restore path to be read from /private/etc/paths

Tags: macos, path

I used the how to from 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-install-macos.html

to install AWS CLI on macOS.
After executing command `source ~/.bash_profile` it seems that my default PATH location from file /private/etc/paths was lost.

/private/etc/paths file content:

```
/usr/bin/vim /private/etc/paths

/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

~/.bash_profile file content:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.6
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

For example next command cant find the location of basic files installed in /usr/bin/:
-bash: vim: command not found

Is it a way to restore path to be reading from /private/etc/paths?

```
echo $PATH
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Users/<myusername>/bin:/Library/Python/3.6/bin/
```

Also I can't use the same command to reread from the location

```
source /private/etc/paths
-bash: /usr/local/bin: is a directory
-bash: /usr/bin: is a directory
-bash: /bin: is a directory
-bash: /usr/sbin: is a directory
-bash: /sbin: is a directory
```

Comment: There has to be a second `export PATH ...` somewhere which breaks your default path. Otherwise `echo $PATH` wouldn't show: `...:/Users/<myusername>/bin:/Library/Python/3.6/bin/`! Please fix your ugly */private/etc/paths* content: 1. remove empty lines 2. remove spaces and /private/etc/paths (/private/etc/paths is **no** directory)!

Comment: Yep it seems that there was error somewhere in this file in previous steps. It seems like I forgot to attach `:$PATH` in the end. Is it a way to use default file location? Now I added all the default paths in `.bash_profile` and all works nice. Just want to be configured in correct and clear way

Comment: Adding the default paths to your bash profile is just duct-taping...

Answer (score 2):

1. Fix your /private/etc/paths content:

   The default content is:

   ```
   /usr/local/bin
   /usr/bin
   /bin
   /usr/sbin
   /sbin
   ```

   If you want to include /usr/bin/vim (but only if vim is a folder containing some executables - the macOS installed vim exec is /usr/bin/vim!) modify the content to:

   ```
   /usr/local/bin
   /usr/bin/vim
   /usr/bin
   /bin
   /usr/sbin
   /sbin
   ```
2. You have another (superior) `export PATH` line somewhere (i.e. bash config files) with the following content:

   ```
   export PATH="/Users/<myusername>/bin:/Library/Python/3.6/bin/:*"
   ```

   with *= either completely missing or a falsely defined PATH variable (e.g. Path instead of PATH)

   At least it doesn't inherit the standard paths defined by /private/etc/paths

   This first PATH export and the second in your ~/.bash_profile then yield something broken like:

   ```
   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Users/<myusername>/bin:/Library/Python/3.6/bin/
   ```

   as PATH

Comment: Are you sure about including `/usr/bin/vim` verbatim in `/etc/paths`?

Comment: @patrix I assumed the OP added a **folder** vim or installed some 3rd party vim in /usr/bin/vim ;-). But I will add an explanation/exclusion; thx

Comment: I think it's just bad formatting in the question and they used vim to open the file in the first line of the code block.